# No embedded resource found

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I have a xamarin forms application where the very first page has a image control which displays a embedded resource. Often, when i run the application, it fails during start-up with following error:

```
[libc] WARNING: generic atexit() called from legacy shared library
[monodroid-gc] GREF GC Threshold: 46800
[MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
[MonoDroid] Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: No embeddedresources found for SeeVee.StartPage
[MonoDroid]   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject view, System.Type callingType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml[StartPage] (SeeVee.StartPage view, System.Type callingType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at SeeVee.StartPage.InitializeComponent () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at SeeVee.StartPage..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at SeeVee.App.GetMainPage () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at SeeVee.Android.MainActivity+<OnCreate>d__0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono] 
[mono] Unhandled Exception:
[mono] Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: No embeddedresources found for SeeVee.StartPage
[mono]   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject view, System.Type callingType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml[StartPage] (SeeVee.StartPage view, System.Type callingType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at SeeVee.StartPage.InitializeComponent () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at SeeVee.StartPage..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at SeeVee.App.GetMainPage () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at SeeVee.Android.MainActivity+<OnCreate>d__0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt] [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: No embeddedresources found for SeeVee.StartPage
[mono-rt]   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlLoader.Load (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject view, System.Type callingType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   at Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml[StartPage] (SeeVee.StartPage view, System.Type callingType) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   at SeeVee.StartPage.InitializeComponent () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   at SeeVee.StartPage..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   at SeeVee.App.GetMainPage () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   at SeeVee.Android.MainActivity+<OnCreate>d__0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I have to rebuild the app in xamarin studio and re-run and it works. Phew! this gets very tiring sometimes. I hope xamarin is aware of this silly bug and will fix it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fix that worked for me was the following

In the main project `.csproj` file, I found that all my `.xaml` files where formatted like this :

`<EmbeddedResource Include="Source\Home\HomeContentView.xaml">
    <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>
</EmbeddedResource>`

Except one, the one that was failing had an extra line which looked like this

`<LogicalName>MyProject.Home.HomeContentView.xaml</LogicalName>`

Removing this line fixed the issue. I also saved my files, cleaned and rebuilt the project.

Comment: At my end, I had removed UWP project, but didn't remove related on platform statement from the app file which was loading font family. Removing that worked. Thanks for your hint.

Comment: mine was missing the Generator tag

Answer (score 17):

It's a [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=21111). For some reason its status is **RESOLVED FIXED**, but it doesn't seem fixed at all. On XS on mac anyway.

As a workaround, the file that the exception is thrown in, SomeClass.g.cs, just make an edit to that one generated file, save it, and build again. A bit faster than rebuilding everything.

Of course this means every time you change a .xaml file, you have to build twice.

Comment: amazingly years later that bug is not fixed and the workaround still works. thank you :D

Comment: Thank you akevan

Comment: Still broken in Visual Studio for Mac v8.4.8, and this is still the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: Still works now on VS Mac 8.10.6 - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar error and fixed it by correcting the class name in my xaml file.
I mean in the x:Class attribute of my page.

Comment: Same here, but the issue was triggered by some leading whitespace in the x:Class attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac. I changed my quote char from double quotes (") to single quotes (') and formatted my files. Suddenly I started to get this error whenever the formatted `ContentPage` was Initialised.

I went back into:

```
'Visual Studio Community' -> 'Preferences' -> 'Source Code' -> 'Code Formatting' -> 'XML document' -> 'XML Format' -> Quote char
```

changed it back to double quotes, formatted the documents that I had formatted with the single quotes back to double quotes (`'Edit'->'Format'->'Format Document'`) and now it is working perfectly again.

This fixed my problem with:

```
'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException has been thrown'
'No embeddedresource found for YourNamespace.YourContentPageName'
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to visual studio 2017 and latest version of Xamarin this happened to me no matter what I tried.  It was the correct class name. Nothing changed in the XAML for this to make sense and to keep getting kicked out of the ios build and android build with the embedded resource not found error. The only solution is to save your xaml and code behind in a notepad then delete that class permanently from your project.  Add a new ContentPage to your Xamarin.Forms portable project and name it something different.  Paste your code back in and save. Update your project to look for that new ContentPage name. Then it will work for you again.

Comment: I had to do the same, more or less.  Sucks.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to check whether the item is in the Remove list in an ItemGroup  which could have been excluded in the past: